# Missing partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello i want to show @detail in /notes/show_html.slim, but i have error **Missing partial details/_detail with** how i can output @detail in /notes/show.html.slim

***routes.rb***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/about_me', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :notes do
    resources :details
  end
end
```

***details_controller.rb***

```
class DetailsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
    @detail = Detail.new
  end

  def create
    @note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
    @detail = @note.details.build(detail_param)
    if @detail.save
    redirect_to note_path(@note)
  end
end

  def destroy
    @note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
    @detail = @note.details.find(params[:id])
    @detail.destroy
    redirect_to note_path(@note)
  end

  private

  def detail_param
    params.require(:detail).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

and views

***/notes/show.html.slim***

```
#note
  #post_content
   .show
     h1 = @note.title
     = render @note.details #or = render 'details/show'?
   .date
    p Created #{time_ago_in_words(@note.created_at)} ago
    hr
   -if @note.user_id == current_user.id
    p=link_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(@note), class: 'btn btn-primary'
    p=link_to 'delete', note_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Delete note?" },  class: 'btn btn-primary'
    p=link_to  'Add details', new_note_detail_path(@note), class: 'btn btn-primary'
    hr
   .body
      p #{@note.body}
```

***/details/show.html.slim***

```
div class="details"
  p #{@detail.body}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`= render @note.details`, expects to render each object (`detail`) using a template called `details/_detail.html.slim`

You can read about it [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rendering-collections-in-rails)

`details/show.html.slim` is meant to render the show action for the specific resource.

`details/_detail.html.slim` is meant to e.g. render each row for a `details/index.html.slim` passing the `detail` object.

If your `show` template really fits, then you can do something like this:

```
# /notes/show.html.slim
= render @note.details.each do |detail|
  = render 'details/show', detail: detail
```

--

```
# /details/show.html.slim
- detail ||= @detail
div class="details"
  p #{detail.body}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is consistent with how collection rendering works in Rails.
`@note.details` is a collection of objects, so when you do a `render @note.details` Rails will loop over the collection, and for each object in the collection determines which partial to use by calling `to_partial_path` on that object. In this case, the method will return `details/detail` so that's what Rails will try to render.
If you want to specify a different partial, you need to change the rendering to something like:

`= render partial: 'OTHER_PARTIAL', collection: @note.details`

Answer (score 0):

Partial name in Rails should start with _ (_partial.html.slim) and next you can

```
<%= render :partial => 'tasks/your_partial' %>
```

More info you can find [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Answer (score 0):

The partial syntax for rails is **_name_of_partial.html.erb/slim/haml**
Thats the error you are getting.
My advice to you is to stick with the conventions, if you wish to render the details data once again, in another view you should have a partial **_data.html.slim** inside your details views folder, so you can call it from the show on detail and from the show on your notes show, it could be like this

**notes/show.html.slim**

```
#note
#post_content
 .show
   h1 = @note.title
   = render 'details/data' data: @details
   .date
   p Created #{time_ago_in_words(@note.created_at)} ago
   hr
   -if @note.user_id == current_user.id
   p=link_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(@note), class: 'btn btn-primary'
   p=link_to 'delete', note_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Delete note?" },  class: 'btn btn-primary'
   p=link_to  'Add details', new_note_detail_path(@note), class: 'btn btn-primary'
   hr
   .body
     p #{@note.body}
```

**details/_data.html.slim**

```
div class="details"
  p #{data.body}
```

I also suggest you to read throughly http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

From [Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

> Partials are named with a leading underscore to distinguish them from regular views

So you need to change **details/show.html.slim** to **details/_show.html.slim**.

After that, you can use partials in your notes/show.html.slim like

```
= render partial: "details/show", collection: @note.details, as: :detail
```

Note that to render a collection, using `:collection` option is shorter than an each loop.

And details/_show.html.slim is like

```
# details/_show.html.slim
div.details
  p= detail.body
```