# Assigning jBuilder output to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I have a Ruby on Rails App that uses jbuilder. I am using jbuilder to help render json responses. Is there a way assign the jbuilder partial to a variable without rendering the result? I have been trying to do something like below, but I am getting this `undefined method 'key' for nil:NilClass` error. It seems I am not correctly passing the users model to the `user.json.jbuilder` Can anyone offer any help?

```
context = ActionController::Base.new.view_context
user_json = JbuilderTemplate.new(context) do |json|
 json.partial! "/users_api/user.json.jbuilder", user: user
end.target!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the JSON from Jbuilder directly with `JbuilderTemplate` combined with `.target!`, but the filename is required to start with an underscore. Starting the filename with and underscore denotes it as a partial which means it can't be rendered directly.

References ([How to render Jbuidler partials inside a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920951/how-to-render-jbuidler-partials-inside-a-model), [Missing partial in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088058/missing-partial-in-rails/34088379))

Return JSON directly (calls `_user.json.jbuilder`)

```
    context = ActionController::Base.new.view_context
    user_json = JbuilderTemplate.new(context) do |json|
      json.partial! "/users_api/user.json.jbuilder", user: user
    end.target!
```

Render JSON (calls `user.json.jbuilder` which call `_user.json.jbuilder`)

```
    render "/users_api/user.json.jbuilder"
```

`user.json.jbuilder`

```
    json.partial! "/users_api/user.json.jbuilder", user: @user
```

`_user.json.jbuilder`

```
    json.email user.email
    json.name user.name
```